# Getting Network request failed when uploading images with apollo client react native android

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am using ApolloClient to send mutation that contains files (images) but I am getting

```
Error: Network request failed
```

this what I have done to create links

```js
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client' v ==>> "^15.0.0";

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
        uri: API_URL,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          "Accept":"application/json"
        },
      });
```

this to handle errors

```js
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error"; v ==>> "^3.3.20"

   const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
        if (graphQLErrors)
          graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
            console.log(
              `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
            ),
          );
      
        if (networkError) console.log(`[Network zaid error]: ${networkError}`);
      });
```

then :

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        link: from([errorLink,uploadLink]),
        defaultOptions: {
          watchQuery: {
            fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
            errorPolicy: 'none'
          },
          mutate: {
            mutation: "DocumentNode",
            errorPolicy: 'none'
          },
        },
      });
```

then I called the mutation :

```js
       await client.mutate({

        mutation:
        gql`  
         mutation($data: PostCreatInput!, $files: [CustomCreateImages!]!) {
           createpost(data: $data, files: $files) {
              id
          }}`,

        variables: {

          data: {****},

          files:[{file:ReactNativeFile}]

         }
      
      
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response
      }).catch(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response
      })
```

i used ReactNativeFile generated by `apollo-upload-client`

```js
          new ReactNativeFile({
            uri:  "file:///storage/***.jpg",
            name: "a.jpg",
            type: "image/jpeg"
          });
```

I am using react native "react-native": "0.62.2"
and I have a live server not using localhost
I did check the server logs this request never left the mobile; there was no record of it on the server.

been stuck all day on it, any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bug with React Native 0.62+ that messes up the configuration for multiform requests. It can be fixed by commenting out line 43 in android/app/src/debug/java/com/maxyride/app/drivers/ReactNativeFlipper.java:

```java
//builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
```